# How to "hide" class names in Javascript ES6?

Tags: javascript, oop, module, ecmascript-6

I'm doing some vanilla Javascript with ES6. My simple code is divided in 3 files like this:

```
// File A
class A { 
    // ...
}

// File B
class B { 
    // ...
}

// File C
class C { 
    constructor() {
        this.a = new A();
        this.b = new B();
    }
}
```

Class A and B are only used in class C, so I would like to "hide" these class names and prevent them from polluting the scope.

How can I do that while keeping them in different files? Maybe I should use the ES6 module feature, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: *Any* module system would help. ES6 modules is certainly the way to go if you already use a transpiler anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ES6 modules.

In files A and B export the classes:

```
// File A
export default class A { 
    // ...
}

// File B
export default class B { 
    // ...
}
```

And import them in file C:

```
import A from './A';
import B from './B';

// File C
class C { 
    constructor() {
        this.a = new A();
        this.b = new B();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, ES6 modules are not supported natively yet, so you should transpile your code using [Babel](https://babeljs.io/). If you want to run your code in browser, you can use [Rollup.js](http://rollupjs.org/) to bundle your modules in one file.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right path, use [modules](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html).

In your case you would have three modules `A`, `B` and `C`. Module `C` will import modules `A` and `B`. Your public API will be the module `C`, preventing `A` and `B` classes from polluting the scope.

Assuming those modules will be in the same directory this will result in following structure.

a.js

```
export default class A { 
    // ...
}
```

b.js

```
export default class B { 
    // ...
}
```

c.js

```
import A from './a'
import B from './b'

export default class C { 
    constructor() {
        this.a = new A();
        this.b = new B();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But once I include c.js into my html, wouldn't the variables A and B be still polluting the scope?

Comment: The way modules work prevents this. Classes A and B won't be visible outside as they are not exported.

Comment: @Thomas: Browsers don't support modules. You have to use a module bundler which combines all files into a single file.